# How to pass variable between php pages correctly where javascript is interactive?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new in this field, and I am currently working on small eCommerce website. Therefore, it would be very much appreciated if somebody can give me any advice or tip, or link the similar question as the answer to this question.

I know this post is pretty long one...however, I wanted to share my situation as precisely as possible so that people understand correctly what I am struggling with. That's why it became long post......

I have a flow and codes as you can see below.

And, where I am stack is that I don't know how I can make "Edit" button works correctly in revieworder.php page while other functions works properly together....

So, my question is how can I achieve following things simultaneously ?

1. passing variables from revieworder.php to options.php and deliveryinformation.php page when user press “Edit” button in revieworder.php page
2. after user jump to deliveryinformation.php page from revieworder.php page, javascript for country selection still works properly (by changing the country, javascript returns shippingfee, retrieved from DB, depending on the selected country in the same page(deliveryinformation.php).)
3. shippingfee, totalfee and country data are passed in following flow properly
   revieworder.php → delieveryinformation.php → revieworder.php
   revieworder.php → options.php → delieveryinformation.php → revieworder.php

Could you please teach me how I can archive that ?

**Flow of my website is here;**

1st page(options.php): User can choose the detail of product that they would like to order

2nd page(deliveryinformation.php): User is supposed to input information for delivery such as their name, address, and so on. Besides, by changing the country, javascript returns shippingfee, retrieved from DB, depending on the selected country in the same page(deliveryinformation.php).

3rd page(revieworder.php): User can review the detail of product and information for delivery. And user can press “Edit” button to go back to options.php page or deliveryinformation.php page to change their input

**Codes;**

options.php

```
<form name="selection" method="POST" action="deliveryinformation.php">  
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="dropdownforoption" name="options" class="form-control">
      <option value="" select="selected">Option</option>
      <option value="babysname">Baby's name</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea id="request" name="request" placefolder="please type your request"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="dropdownforsize" name="size" class="form-control">
      <option value="" select="selected">Size</option>
      <option value="27cm x 24cm">27cm x 24cm</option>
      <option value="specialsize">special size</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button id="delivery" type="submit" onclick="return onclickvalidation()">Proceed to develivery information</button>
</form>
```

deliveryinformation.php

```
<?php
  $options = $_POST['options'];
  $request = $_POST['request'];
  $size = $_POST['size'];
>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="toppage.js"></script>
  </head>
...
<form name="delivery" method="POST" action="revieworder.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="options" value="<?= $options; ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="request" value="<?= $request; ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?= $size; ?>"/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Name</p>
      <p>Country</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="please type your name">Name</input>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select id="countryselection" name="country" class="form-control">
          <option value="" select="selected">Choose your country</option>
          <option value="germany" select="selected">Germany</option>
          <option value="other" select="selected">Other</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>shipping fee</p>
        <p>total fee</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="shippingfee">EUR <input type="hidden" name="shippingfee" id="shippingfees2"><span id="shippingfees">xxx</span></input></p>
        <p class="totalfee">EUR <input type="hidden" name="totalfee" id="totalfees2"><span id="totalfees">xxx</span></input></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
..
</html>
```

toppage.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#countryselection').change(function(){
    if($('#countryselection').val()!='Germany'){
        var country = 'Other'
    }else{var country = 'Germany'}

    var priceforframe = document.delivery.framefees.value;

    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: '/shippingfee.php', 
        data: {'countryforshippingfee': country},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 

            document.getElementById("shippingfees2").value = data;
            $('#shippingfees').html(data);

            var total = data + 50;

            document.getElementById("totalfees2").value = total;
            $('#totalfees').html(total);
        }
    });
}); 
});

function submitForm(action){
  document.getElementById('forminreviewpage').action = action;
  document.getElementById('forminreviewpage').submit();
}
```

revieworder.php

```
<?php
  $options = $_POST['options'];
  $request = $_POST['request'];
  $size = $_POST['size'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $country = $_POST['country'];
  $shippingfee = $_POST['shippingfee'];
  $totalfee = $_POST['totalfee'];
?>
<html>
..
<form id="forminreviewpage" name="confirmation" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="options" value="<?= $options; ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="request" value="<?= $request; ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?= $size; ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?= $name; ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="country" value="<?= $country; ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="shippingfee" value="<?= $shippingfee; ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="totalfee" value="<?= $totalfee; ?>"/>
</form>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p><?= $options; ?></p>
      <p><?= $request; ?></p>
      <p><?= $size; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button id="editbutton" onclick="submitForm('options.php')">Edit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p><?= $name; ?></p>
      <p><?= $country; ?></p>
      <p><?= $shippingfee; ?></p>
      <p><?= $totalfee; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button id="editbutton" onclick="submitForm('deliveryinformation.php')">Edit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="orderbutton" onclick="submitForm('ordered.php')">Order</button></br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you so much for your help and best regards,
Hiro

Comment: My best suggestion is to use a framework like CodeIgniter or Laravel

Comment: @fatman, it's very much appreciated that you gave me an advice. I am going to see how Codelgniter and Laravel works as well as sessions as other people recommended me. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sessions will enable pages within your site to access a 'pool' of data - providing you set session variables yourself. This can easily be done in PHP - [see this page](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) on W3 for basic details, there are plenty of other sites on the net with easy walkthroughs of sessions once you've got the basic concept.

I'm not quite sure what you're asking in question two. Is it that you want the second page to automatically know the user's country? If so, this could be achieved by assigning a session variable on the previous page, or by using geo-location - see help [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

As for question three, achieving proper flow is an architectural issue - you'll need to ensure that the pages visited by the user structured to only allow the through-flow that you want. Without spending hours working through your code, I should imagine this can again be achieved through assigning session variables when a page is successfully 'completed' and ready to move to the next page.

Sessions are powerful, and will allow you to control a lot of user data to ease their experience of your site throughout their period of use. Just be careful about what session data you record though - it should always be the minimum amount possible, and not containing any data that could compromise the user's personal details, or their account - i.e. don't store their username and password, just store an int of '1' or '0' if they pass authentication.

Hope that helps.

Comment: also - you tagged this as 'javascript' and 'jquery' but then suggest you don't want javascript to be used.

Comment: thank you so much for your sincere answer. I will go through W3 page to learn sessions as it seems question one and three can be achieved both by sessions.   Regarding question two, I was thinking in my mind that "if we would pass $country value(e.g. germany) from revieworder.php page to deliveryinformation.php page and set value in first option tag such as <option value="<?= $country; ?>" select="selected"><?= $country; ?></option> in deliveryinformation.php page, probably first function in toppage.js would not work anymore". I will update this post as soon as I solve. Thanks again !